# deep learning convolutional net for self driving car with sensor input only

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, dl4j

So I am trying to learn deep learning neural networks with dl4j.
And here is my question: I am having a car simulation and I have 21 sensor data for the input. Notice not pictures, but sensor data such as speed, distances in the front of the car and angle to track! when configuring NeuralNetConfiguration? thanks for your help. or shouldn't I use the convolutional network?
 I am totally new to this and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Convnets are not the most suited models for this kind of input.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: my most desired output is a choice of action like the steering and acceleration of the car